# (firefox:6252): Pango-WARNING **: shaping failure, expect ugly output. shape-engine='BasicEngineFc

Tags: firefox

I've been facing a rather unusual problem with browsing websites on Firefox, its never happen before and the weird part is that Chromium is able to load all the websites flawlessly, its only Firefox going bonkers. Some Websites like OMGubuntu, facebook and vimeo load making a mess on the screen.

This is the error message I received when I tried opening Firefox in safemode from the terminal.

```
(firefox:6252): Pango-WARNING **: shaping failure, expect ugly output. shape-
engine='BasicEngineFc', font='@font-face:Droid Sans 17.3330078125', text=' '
```

Any one out there with the same problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I solved it myself! thanks to this forum thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=830110I , I recall having installed a large collection of ttf fonts that I downloaded off deviantart deleting some of those fonts from **/usr/share/fonts/trutype** solved the problem.